# How to add group as reviewers in Merge Request by non-group member in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

In a project if we give @GROUP NAME in the comment of merge request by any non-group member then for that non-group member that group DL is not displaying. Could you please let me know how the non-group members can use that internal group?

Answer (score 0):

The auto-complete list for group mentions only populate with groups where a user is a direct member. Nevertheless, the user can still mention the group and it will work even if it doesn't show up in the auto-complete list.

Just make sure to use the full path.

For example, if you have a subgroup in `gitlab.example.com/group/subgroup`, you need to `@group/subgroup`.